# How to delete all data from MySQL table and populate table with new data

Tags: java, mysql

I am writing a java function to delete all data from MySQL table and then write new data in it. following is my function.

```
public void editsnack(ArrayList snames)
{
System.out.println("Snack Names "+snames);
Statement _snacksListStmt = null;
Statement _deleteTableDtataStmt = null;
try
{
    _snacksListStmt = fCon.createStatement();
    _deleteTableDtataStmt = fCon.createStatement();
    int i=0;

        for(i=0;i<snames.size();i++)
        {
        String _name = snames.get(i).toString();
        String _deleteTableData ="TRUNCATE TABLE snacklist";
        _deleteTableDtataStmt.executeUpdate(_deleteTableData);
        String _snackListQuery ="insert into snacklist(snackName)values('"+_name+"')";
        System.out.println("Query ");
        System.out.println(_snackListQuery);
        _snacksListStmt.executeUpdate(_snackListQuery);
        }
}
```

Note that after deleting data successfully, these lines

```
System.out.println("Query ");
System.out.println(_snackListQuery);
```

are printing correct values, however values are not being stored in the table.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: First of all, you're deleting all data for each item you are inserting. So move the `TRUNCATE` code to *before* the `for`-loop

Comment: Also.. That SQL can contain injections.

Comment: @NoLifeKing post your 1st comment as an answer, so i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're deleting all data for each item you are inserting.

So move the `TRUNCATE` code to before the `for`-loop

And see if you can sanitize the snack-names before adding them in the SQL, or they could cause sql-injections

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if your connection is set on autoCommit or not you'd have to call `fCon.commit()` to commit your transaction.
Also you should always close your statements when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the delete query in the for loop, you are truncating the data after each insert. With your current logic only the last insert will reamin in the table and all other data will be truncated. Move the delete query outside of for loop and try:

```
     String _deleteTableData ="TRUNCATE TABLE snacklist";
    _deleteTableDtataStmt.executeUpdate(_deleteTableData);


  for(i=0;i<snames.size();i++)
    {
    String _name = snames.get(i).toString();
    String _snackListQuery ="insert into snacklist(snackName)values('"+_name+"')";
    System.out.println("Query ");
    System.out.println(_snackListQuery);
    _snacksListStmt.executeUpdate(_snackListQuery);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code below..

```
    public void editsnack(ArrayList snames)
    {
    System.out.println("Snack Names "+snames);
    Statement _snacksListStmt = null;
    Statement _deleteTableDtataStmt = null;
    try
    {
    _snacksListStmt = fCon.createStatement();
    _deleteTableDtataStmt = fCon.createStatement();

    String _deleteTableData ="TRUNCATE TABLE snacklist";
    _deleteTableDtataStmt.executeUpdate(_deleteTableData);

    int i=0;

        for(i=0;i<snames.size();i++)
        {
        String _name = snames.get(i).toString();
        String _snackListQuery ="insert into snacklist (snackName) values ('"+_name+"')";
        System.out.println("Query ");
        System.out.println(_snackListQuery);
        _snacksListStmt.executeUpdate(_snackListQuery);
        }
}
```